# change 'NULL' values in column to blank values - Tibco Spotfire

Tags: null, spotfire, tibco

I am trying to connect data from SQL DB, and there are NULL values in many columns (10 Columns). While Connecting to spotfire using SQL (using ISNULL function) these NULL values are changed to 0.

Since these values are changed to 0 there are few calculations being executed.

I wanted to change these NULL to blank instead of Zero, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes... just change your `ISNULL(columnName,0)` to `ISNULL(columnName,'')`. However, this changes the datatype of the column.

Comment: don't forget to accept this answer if it worked @BULB